# I want vs-code to give a warning for undefined properties in a java-script file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Suppose I have the following code:

```
const variable = {
    a: 2
}

console.log(variable.a);
console.log(variable.b);
```

Is it possible to config vs code so that it gives warning that `b` is undefined? currently, it does not say anything about it.

Comment: You'll only be able to get guesses unless there plugin actually runs your code (and all branches) since the object could be modified at any time to include that property.

Comment: Stuff like this is why Typescript exists. Instead of having `variable`, simply be an `Object`, you’d make a specific type for this and it would guaranteed only have certain properties, and then the Typescript compiler would fail to compile into JavaScript if you tried to call an undefined property. This is probably going to be your best bet, as it doesn’t require special editor settings to catch on every single developer’s machine, and plain JavaScript is intentionally loose about undefined properties and whatnot.

Comment: @Nate thanks for your note.  But I'm developing react native.  And it still does not seat easy with typescript

Answer (score 0):

ESlint extension should resolve your problem.

Comment: I tired Eslint but it is only able to detect undefined variables. for example, it complains about `console.log(some_undefined_variable);` but it can not detect that a property `b` of the object is undefined.(`console.log(variable.b);`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use TypeScript annotations, see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html#object-literals-are-open-ended